# Height not working while setting it with calc() in stylus

Tags: css, stylus

I am using stylus in my React project. I am using calc function to set height of some divs. But the calc is not not getting applied. On the client side when I inspect the element, I see the height attribute as calc but the element doesn't obey it. This is how I am setting height

```
.ht-full-70 {
  height: calc(100% - 70px) !important;
}
```

When I inspect it, I can see the style there

[image]

But element is not taking this. It remains unaffected by this.

Comment: I guess either the parent has no height set or your element is not block like

Comment: First I would check the parent to see what height this has. Worth noting when I inspect an element with a calc height this it will display that, not what it works out as.

Comment: Okay so it's parent div has height: calc(100%-20px) which also doesn't work and then next parent has height 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a wrap div around the element that you are trying to set a width for. This will make sure that the element has a set starting point for percentages if you give this wrap a height too. I demonstrate it in this snippet.

```css
.ht-wrap {
  padding-top:20px;
  display;inline-block;
  height:280px;
  background-color:blue;
}

.ht-full-70 {
  padding:6px;
  display;inline-block;
  height: calc(100% - 70px) !important;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="ht-wrap">
  <div class="ht-full-70">
    <p>Text.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `.ht-full-70`'s parent tag doesn't set `height`

You should set `height` of `.ht-full-70`'s parent tag.

Comment: Okay so it's parent div has height: calc(100%-20px) which also doesn't work and then next parent has height 100%.

Comment: Set body's `height`. For example, `body{height: 100vh}`

Comment: But when I set height:700px then it works. calc should also work then, right?

Comment: No it doesn't. That's what the question is. It works when I set it like height:700px but calc doesn't work.

Comment: @ApurvG Can I see your WHOLE CODE? (HTML, CSS)

Comment: @ApurvG I think.. it's a problem with `display`, so I need a code HTML, CSS

Comment: @ApurvG Try to add `display: inline-block` or `display: block`.